# Что означает запись typedef struct {} *name;

Tags: c++, typedef

Допустим, что я захотел написать **typedef struct** с именем ссылки **name** на этот неименованный тип struct: `typedef struct{} name;`. Я осознаю, что здесь создается не новый тип с именем name, а только ссылка с именем name на неименованный тип struct. Но такая запись: `typedef struct {} * name;` вводит меня в замешательство, ведь я не знаю чем эта запись отличается от первой, зачем она нужна и как с ней обращаться! Надеюсь, я правильно и понятно сформулировал проблему, надеюсь Вы поможете!

Comment: В первом случаи name  это не ссылка, а имя   типа, а во втором случаи это имя указателя  на  тип. Можно объявить указатель следующим образом: name ptr = nullptr;

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Имя типа - это так: `struct name{};`, где name является именем типа, а мой первый пример - name является именем ссылки на неименованный тип. Я слышал что именно в этом разница между простым объявлением структуры и моим первым примером из вопроса.

Comment: Сначала нужно понять что такое ссылка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typedef struct {} * name;` эквивалентно вот этому:

```
struct Unnamed {};
typedef Unnamed * name;
```

После этого, `name` означает `Unnamed *` (указатель на `Unnamed`).

Comment: то есть это указатель на неименованную структуру?

Comment: @CodePenguin32 Точно.

Comment: а в чем заключается смысл такого описания структуры?

Comment: @CodePenguin32 Имеете в виду, зачем это делать? Хз, я редко видел, чтобы так делали.